# Error while trying to start apache2

Tags: apache2

The following message is reported to me when I try to start apache2.

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                
ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
[fail]
```

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: ya am using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `80` port is taken. If you have skype or other software that may use 80 port, turn it off and try again.

Comment: To add to this.  If you are using skype, instead of closing it you can go to `Skype Options`, click `Advanced > Connection` and uncheck `Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
su -
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```